# Getting the response's true wire size from a jersey clientof a HTTP jersey response that is chunked and gzipped by a filter

Tags: java, gzip, jersey-client

I use a jersey 1.8 client with GZIP encoding enabled via filter:

```
mClient.addFilter(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
WebResource.Builder builder = wr.type("multipart/mixed").accept("multipart/mixed").header("Authorization", mAuthToken).entity(s);
```

with a chunked and gzipped response:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;   boundary=Boundary_10523_700954032_1474654357881
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

What I want to know is how to get the wire length (the 7K length while the message was still compressed, before the filter got to it and uncompressed it to 70k which is what you get from the response entities).

I'd like the equivalent of what Eclipse's TCP/IP Monitor window shows as the Reponse Size in bytes, either the content or total size would be fine:

```
Size: 7001 (7722) bytes
```

But since chunk and gzip handling is done for me (and I don't want to change that), I am not privvy to the "wire size" which is what I need to know.

Does anyone know if the pre-decompressed size (but not the content) is available in a simple way from the client response in this scenario?

Alternatively, is there a way to have the GZIP filter record the compressed size in a header to make its way to the surface so I can use it?

Or is there already some filter used for recording the pre-uncompressed wire size that works in the presence of chunk encoding?